# system of non-linear equations given in matrix form ( using fsolve)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations using `fsolve`. The system is given in the matrix form (image), u_i being the unknowns.

plz suggest how can I create the function to be given input to `fsolve`.
thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the documentation for `fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html). You can create a function handle, either for a function in its own file or anonymously, and call it using `fsolve`:

```
h = @(U) P'*U.^2;  % function handle
U_next = fsolve(h, U);
```

If you are doing an inner product, you also need to make sure that your left-hand side has the same number of *columns* as your right-hand side has *rows*. For instance, if you have some arbitrary 4x1 matrix `P` and initial 1x4 vector `U`, you have to take some transposes to make sure that your inner product works out:

```
P = rand(4, 1);  % random column vector
U = rand(1, 4);  % random row vector
h = @(U) P'*U'.^2;  % (1x4) * (4x1) = scalar result
```

Or if you are trying to do element-wise multiplication:

```
h = @(U) P'.*U.^2;  % (1x4) .* (1x4) = (1x4) result with element-wise multiplication
```